# How can I use a guava class (HashMultiset) from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, guava

Here are some of my failed attempts:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset

// 1. This does not work!
// val foo1:HashMultiset[Int] = HashMultiset[Int].create()

// 2. Neither does this!
// val foo2:HashMultiset[Int] = new HashMultiset[Int]()

// foo1.add(1)
```

In the first case it complains that HashMultiset is not a value.

In the second case it says that HashMultiset[Int] does not have a constructor.

Is there some additional magic I need to work in order to use this guava class from Scala?

UPDATE0: I'm using Scala 2.11.2 with Guava 18.0 in case that matters!

Comment: `val foo1:HashMultiset[Int] = HashMultiset.create()` might work.

Comment: "cannot resolve symbol create" :-(

Comment: `val foo1: HashMultiset[Int] = HashMultiset.create()` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: What versions of scala and guava are you using?

Comment: val foo1:HashMultiset[Int] = HashMultiset.create[Int]() 
works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `HashMultiset[Int].create()` is that, though `HashMultiset` is a class with a type parameter, `create` is a static method. When you call a static method, you do not use a type parameter on the class name.  Therefore, `HashMultiset.create()` should be enough. I assume the `create` method *does* have a type parameter, so it would be valid to write `HashMultiset.create[Int]()`.